# Animating a circle of lights

Tags: math

I am trying to create some basic animations for a set of RGB LEDs. Normal linear animations are simple enough using loops and counters to vary the light colour.

What I have is a ring of 24 LEDs and want to be able to apply animations to them so that the effect, say a simple colour wipe, occurs from top to bottom, or side to side (basically any given direction).

I have not made any progress worth sharing, other than storing an array of each "row" of LEDs:

```
0 => 0
1 => 1, 23
2 => 2, 22
3 => 3, 21
and so on
```

This is a crude solution, and I am hoping there are better ways using cos/tan perhaps.

My question is how to address each LED in sequence when performing an animation from top to bottom (or starting at any n degrees).

Comment: The question, as it stands, is quite vague. You could do any kind of effect which will be implemented differently as long as you have an interface to set the i-th led rgb components.

Comment: I have added a summarised question at the bottom. I'm basically trying to access each LED when animating from top to bottom of the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigonometry is relevant if you want to go from a single number (an angle) to a pair of numbers (coordinates of a point on a circle). Your LED addresses seem to be single numbers in the range 0 to 23. They essentially are angles (one every 360/24 = 15 degrees, so you don't need an angle to coordinate conversion.

What you do need is a way to model rotational symmetry, but that is simply modular arithmetic (working mod 24). To give some idea, here is a Python script which could be used to "wipe" from any of the 24 points:

```
def wipe_from(i):
    leds = [[i]]
    for j in range(1,12):
        leds.append([(i+j) % 24, (i-j) % 24])
    leds.append([(i+12)%24])
    return leds
```

For example, `wipe_from(0)` corresponds to what you already have, and `wipe_from(5)` is:

```
[[5], [6, 4], [7, 3], [8, 2], [9, 1], [10, 0], [11, 23], [12, 22], [13, 21], [14, 20], [15, 19], [16, 18], [17]]
```

Comment: Fantastic answer John, thank you kindly. I think the reason I thought to use the angles was to work out an x,y coordinate so that when the transition occurs, I could fade each LED evenly over the period (say 10 seconds). Because the spacing between each "row" increases towards the middle of the circle, I will need to play around with my timer loop I imagine. Thank you again.